# How to check if a sidebar checkbox is clicked in streamlit app

Tags: python, streamlit

I wrote the code as follows to create checkboxes for streamlit app in a for loop.
How can I develop the code to check weather a box is clicked or not? I did it in the following way but it doesn't work in this way.

```
#I created data frame called df in another function.

names = ["df1","df2"]

def create_checkboxes (names :List[str], df):
  checkboxes = {}
  for name in names:
     checkboxes[name] = st.sidebar.checkbox(name, key=name, value=True)


  dfs = []
  for key, value in checkboxes.items():
      checkboxes[key] == "df1"
      dfs.append(df_list[0])
      checkboxes[key] == "df2"
      dfs.append(df_list[1])

   if len(dfs) > 1:
      df = pd.concat(dfs)

return df, checkboxes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this approach, using an `if` condition.
First set the checkboxex value to `False`, but you can still keep it as `True` if you want:

```py
checkboxes[name] = st.sidebar.checkbox(name, key=name, value=False)
```

Refactor the loop to:

```py
...
dfs = []
for key, value in checkboxes.items():
    if value:
        dfs.append(df[key])

if len(dfs) > 1:
    df = pd.concat(dfs)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find the value inside streamlit's `session_state` dictionary by its corresponding key.

So you can retrieve the value with `st.session_state[key]`

Example:

```py
checkbox = st.checkbox('test', key='someKey', value=True)

# retrieve value
is_clicked = st.session_state['someKey']
```